# Ruby : Using NET::SFTP i am unable to pass directory path dynamically

Tags: ruby, net-sftp

For Example: snippet of the code
fname=gets.to_s
sftp.download!("/Users/#{fname}", ".")

It gives me download.rb error with no such file(2) under on_open. But the same works when i am mentioning the full path directly on the path. Its not working only when i am doing string interpolation by getting the userinput. Please suggest with examples..

Comment: Please post a *complete* example plus sample input - what value do you provide for `fname` ? Did you check whether `fname` contains additional characters (e.g. line breaks) that might cause the error?